# apache shiro: authc.loginUrl doesn't work

Tags: java, security, shiro

I configured Shiro as follows:

```
        [main]



        [users]

        ...

        [roles]

        ...

        [urls]

        /welcome.xhtml = anon
        /overview.xhtml = authc
```

As you can imagine 'welcome.xhtml' contains my login-form. If I am not logged into the application and I try to access overview.xhtml I am thrown to 'login.jsp' that is not existend in my application!

Further, If I add following:

```
authc.loginUrl = /welcome.xhtml
```

to the main part of shiro config i get this error by starting tomcat:

```
ERROR: Exception starting filter SecurityFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.isTypedProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:241)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:349)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:161)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:124)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter.applySecurityManager(IniShiroFilter.java:353)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter.configure(IniShiroFilter.java:321)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter.init(IniShiroFilter.java:292)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.onFilterConfigSet(AbstractShiroFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractFilter.init(AbstractFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    ... 35 more
```

Ehere is my mistake?
cheers...

---

MAVEN POM PART:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use Shiro's .ini configuration, it uses Apache Commons Beanutils 1.7 (or later).  That jar must be in your application's classpath at runtime.

If you're using Maven 2, the dependency will be automatically included (unless someone has explicitly excluded it from your POM).  If you're not using Maven 2, you can download it from here:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your maven dependencies list doesn't include `commons-beanutils`, that's your problem. See my edit to Les Hazelwood's answer for the maven dependency.